# added vs included

Tags: word-usage, verbs, verb-usage

Which is more appropriate:

xyz feature is included in the abc website
**OR**
xyz feature is added to the abc website

when talking about a new software release?

Comment: They're both correct. The choice depends only on whether you want to focus on the fact that this feature is new. If you've just added a feature that most sites already have, you might want to hide the fact that you've just added it.

Answer (score 0):

'Added' *to* something else means it was a later addition to something that already existed. So, if you were speaking about the original software product rather than the specific release, this would be appropriate:

> The feature has been added to the software.

'Included' *in* means that something is already part of something. Something being added is not already part of it, but if you were speaking directly about the updated release rather than the original this would be appropriate:

> This feature is included in the new release.

You can also say 'included *with*' which essentially means the same but suggests that it is somewhat separate. For example, if you said that Microsoft Windows was 'included with' a new PC you acknowledge that they are separate things but when you get one, you get the other as well. Likewise, if your software update was primarily new features but also had a security patch, you might say that the patch comes *with* the update.

Comment: Your two examples strike me as reversed. An initial release **includes** features, and an update **adds** features. Am I misunderstanding you?